# Can not send pusher events from laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I'm trying since hours to use pusher in my laravel app. For this I was following some tutorials but it's still not working and now I'm a nervous wreck.

Here's my code:

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=*ID
PUSHER_APP_KEY=*KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=*SECRET
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=eu
```

**TestEvent**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Wish;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('tests');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/send-test', function(){
    event(new TestEvent());
    return ['message' => 'OK?'];
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Laravel is so big, it's very difficult to know exactly what went wrong, but here's a checklist.

1. Have you changed your broadcast driver in the `.env` file to be pusher?
2. Have you run `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`?
3. Have you compiled your Javascript dependencies with `npm run dev`?
4. Have you added your credentials to the `.env` file?
5. Have you added your cluster to the options section of the pusher area in config/broadcasting.php? You do this like so:

   'options' => [
       'cluster' => 'eu',
       'encrypted' => true
   ],
6. Have you uncommented the following line in config/App.php?

   App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider

If none of the above has worked, can I personally recommend you attempt this tutorial - I've tested this one personally and it should work. https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks in advance, no 1 is my case. Don't forget to composer dumpautoload followed by php artisan clear-compiled and re run php artisan serve.

Comment: My broadcast driver was set to `log`